# Usage of 'would'

Tags: translation, will-would, irrealis-mood

Consider the following sentence

The program was able to communicate with humans using simple software that **would** recognize when certain key words were used.

I want to translate this sentence. Especially, I want to know a usage of the word 'would' :

That is, the above sentence can be rewritten through the following :

The program was able to communicate with humans, and in my **thought**, the program used simple software that was able to recognize when certain key words were used.

Comment: What 'you thought' is not relevant. It looks to me  like a simple past tense of _The program is able to communicate with humans using simple software that_ will _recognise when certain key words are used_.

Comment: I see : It is a past tense of " ... will recognise when certain key words are used." Thank you.